# How to use Django test without Django models?

Tags: python, django, rest, testing

I have a Django app for REST api, but **not** using Django REST Framework.

I don't use models for any tables, only using Raw SQL query. Could've used flask since not using any Django features, but higher ups decided to use Django.

I want to use Django test but digging in the source code I can see both `dumpdata` and `loaddata` which test uses to create Test DB uses app's model. But since I don't have any models how do I test my Django app?

It is OK to use the **actual development DB** for testing.

I see django overrides the `DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS` connection param with the newly created test db params, should I just override the param with the actual `default` db connection param instead?

So

1. can I use django test without models and migrations?
2. can I use `default` database for testing and prevent django from creating a test db?

Comment: Actually, instead of Flask you could've used FastAPI, really easy to use and setup. Django might be too much for just an API.

Comment: @Daviid ... Flask isn't even mentioned here?

Comment: @AKX `Could've used flask since not using any Django features, but higher ups decided to use Django.`

Comment: Ah, my bad. Well, in any case they won't probably OK using FastAPI either then, so bit of a moot point.

Comment: That's where the developers have to push and try to [convince the higher ups](https://medium.com/@ShortHills_Tech/django-vs-fast-api-a-detailed-comparison-df8d00f3c3b2).

Comment: @Daviid Maybe the higher-ups have an idea of e.g. using Django's built-in authentication stuff at some future point, or maybe the rest of the company is 100% Django so having one unfamiliar FastAPI or Flask app is not a great idea?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255406/discussion-between-daviid-and-akx).

Answer (score 1):

Using the actual development DB sounds like a bad idea since you can't easily reproduce it anywhere else (e.g. your CI server).

If you use [Pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.4.x/) (and `pytest-django`), you can use [its setup fixtures](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/database.html#advanced-database-configuration) to import some known default data into the test database instead, e.g. with `loaddata` or just SQL statements.

Comment: but the `loaddata` uses Django model right? also how do I create the fixtures, cause Django `dumpdata` also uses models to get the data!

Using Insert query? what about the 100s of tables? Do I create everything manually?

Comment: Well, you could dump table creation SQL from your development database, yeah – and probably cull it down to the tables you actually need for your tests. Another option is to use `inspectdb` to (try to) auto-generate models to work with...

Answer (score 0):

The  django-app (django-test-without-migrations ) help to run django tests without considering the migrations/migration conflicts.

```
pip install django-test-without-migrations
```

add it it in INSTALLED_APPS

```
 INSTALLED_APPS = (
    # ...
    'test_without_migrations',
)
```

Then run test using the following command

```
python manage.py test --nomigrations
```

--nomigrations make sure your tests won't fail due to the migrations issues.

Reference : https://pypi.org/project/django-test-without-migrations/
Its solution for your first question.

Its recommended to use a separate database for testing.
Specify the test database to be created in  DATABASES  section in setting.py. In the following 'mytestdatabase' will be used for testing.

```
settings.py

DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
        "USER": "mydatabaseuser",
        "NAME": "mydatabase",
        "TEST": {
            "NAME": "mytestdatabase",
        },
    },
}
```

reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/